# How to handle errors when using PasswordResetConfirmView

Tags: django, django-views

I am using `django.auth.contrib` as my session based authentication framework.

I have successfully implemented a reset password feature via `PasswordResetConfirmView` which requires a valid token sent to a user's email to set a new password.

```
 path('password_reset/confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', 
     auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
     template_name='accounts/password_reset/password_reset_confirm.html'), 
     name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

This works fine if the token is valid. However, if the token is not valid (e.g. incorrect or expired), then I predictably get an error:

> Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with arguments '('', '')' not
>   found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['accounts/password_reset/confirm/(?P[^/]+)/(?P[^/]+)/$']

What's the best practice to handle this exception for the user? Ideally I want to catch it and intercept it with "Sorry, your token is invalid." Is there an existing way to do this within the `django.contrib.auth` framework? Looking for the best DRY approach.

**Edit** I am already using the `validlink` context in the template. The error appears to be prior to this:

```
{% block content %}
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
{% if validlink %}

<p>Please enter your new password twice so we can verify you typed it in correctly.</p>

<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<fieldset>
    <div>
        {{ form.new_password1.errors }}
        <label for="id_new_password1">New password:</label>
        {{ form.new_password1 }}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ form.new_password2.errors }}
        <label for="id_new_password2">Confirm password:</label>
        {{ form.new_password2 }}
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Change my password">
</fieldset>
</form>

{% else %}

<p>The password reset link was invalid, possibly because it has already been used.  Please request a new password reset.</p>

{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This is not an error of the `PasswordResetConfirmView`. This is something that *refers* to that view. You apparently used a `{% url .. %}` or `reverse(..)`, etc. but with empty parameters for `uidb64` and `token`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks! Yes for testing purposes I have a `<a href="{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}">Password reset (complete)</a>`. Error resolved!